# I am using Dark Sky API for a weather app, and what does this time mean?

Tags: time, darksky

A bit of code shows `{"time":1578475688`. This doesn't match the time that it was at the time. The time was around 5:27 pm at this time, and I am wondering what this means.

Answer (score 1):

What you got was a UNIX Timestamp. A UNIX Timestamp shows you the time that has passed since Jan 01 1970. (UTC)

You can't really see the time how we normally read it in the number you get but you can look it up through websites like these: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Hopefully this can help you understand what the number you got is.

Comment: Is there a way that I can use Python to convert the unix timestamp to normal time?

Comment: Then I'd recommend using something like `datetime` and `datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')`.

Here's also the Documentation for `strftime`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior